# Why command "read" doesn't work?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read user;
do
echo "Do you want to send the message to $user?"
read response
case $response in
Y|y) echo The message was sent;;
N|n) echo The message was not sent;;
Q|q) exit;;
esac
done < users
```

Why doesn't this code work on Ubuntu? If I run next code, it'll be done;

```
#!/bin/bash
while read user;
do
echo "Do you want to send the message to $user?"
done < users
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read response from terminal so use `</dev/tty` for user response. Or to be more specific, `/proc/$$/fd/0` can be used for taking input from `stdin`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read user;
do
echo "Do you want to send the message to $user?"
IFS="" read -r response  </dev/tty # OR < /proc/$$/fd/0
case $response in
Y|y) echo The message was sent;;
N|n) echo The message was not sent;;
Q|q) exit;;
esac
done < users
```

Comment: The idiomatic way is to use a different file descriptor for reading the file `users`.

Comment: thanks @Inian , you always correct my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Who cares about preserving whitespaces here? the real mistake you make is to read from tty directly and not using a different file descriptor. (Another bad thing about the design is when `response` doesn't match any `case` statement).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I didn' claim reading from `/dev/tty` directly was proper option, just insisted on preserving white-spaces on read operation. Totally in agreement with you. Should have used a different descriptor `read -r line <&3; ....  done 3<users` may be